# jQuery/Ajax content updater keeps jumping on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('#loaddiv').fadeOut('slow').load('/resources/latest.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);
</script>
<div id="loaddiv" style="text-align:center">
<?php
    require_once("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/resources/latest.php");
?>
</div>
```

On every load, the page jumps up, this makes reading the updated content impossible as the use is put higher in the pahe, any idea how I can solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` with `fadeTo` so that the element isn't set to `display:none` while loading.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $( '#loaddiv' ).fadeTo('slow',0).load('/resources/latest.php').fadeTo("slow",1);
}, 5000);
```

however... if you are hiding the div every 5 seconds, isn't that going to interrupt the user anyway?

Comment: Just a placeholder amount, I will of course reduce this. Thanks, I will give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
$ ('#loaddiv').fadeOut('slow').load('/resources/latest.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);
</script>
    <div id="loaddiv" style="text-align:center">
        <?php
            require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/latest.php");
        ?>
    </div>
```

Idk much about what the other moving pieces are but there were a couple syntax errors.

Comment: I also have a CKE textarea and the jQuery keeps jumping to it, does that have any thing to do with this? I used your code but... :(